# Which Azure Serverless option for multiple sensors?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have several devices that are sending data via HTTP in form of JSON and I need to point them to a location where the data would be delivered. Instead of creating a Virtual Machine and running the python web server to listen for incoming data, I would like to use one of the Azure serverless options.
I have read through a lot of documentation and I am still not sure which way to go and I am looking for any suggestion.
So to make it simple,
10 sensors are programmed to send the data as JSON via HTTP
serverless function or something need sot continuously listen for incoming data from these sensors
once data received it needs to be transformed and loaded into an SQL database.

My understanding is that with IoT I have to register every device individually. I currently have only 10 and these devices might be adding in 1000s at the time. SO I need to simply point them to a place to send the data instead of setting each of them within the IoT hub.

I am just looking for direction in terms of which Azure service and logic do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the default use case for Azure IoT Hub. Amongst other protocols devices can [use HTTP to send data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/senddeviceevent).

Add an Azure Stream Analytics service behind it to do your transformations and write to SQL DB.

Comment: My understanding is that with IoT I have to register every device individually. I currently have only 10 and these devices might be adding in 1000s at the time. SO I need to simply point them to a place to send the data instead of setting each of them within the IoT hub.

Comment: Yes, and often this is really what you want (or should want) in terms of security. But if you are really ok with all devices using the same credentials, then you can also go with Event  Hub which offers a similar api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event

Comment: So serverless function would not be the way to go at all?

Comment: and yes all devices will use the same credentials and should point to one single location. Right now I have python script that listens for incoming traffic on a particular port. All sensors are pointed to the IP address of the computer that runs that python script. I just want to do that without using a computer or virtual machine.

Comment: well you could achieve that with an Azure Function or a Container Instance. But I really would advise you to look at a true PaaS service such as Event Hub and Stream Analytics as it sounds like that is all you need